# Edit minified files with intelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea

I am using boostrap and I want to change a background color. For performance reasons, I want to edit the minified file : bootstrap.min.css

Problem : When I search a pattern in this file (`background-color` for example), IntelliJ (and others editors) seem to have some problems with minified files because the file consists of one (very) long line.

How can I fix it?

Up to now, my only solution is to edit it with `vim`. Not so bad but I think that a more readable solution exists. Maybe some params in IntelliJ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Throw it in a beautifier if you want to un-minify it.  A quick Google search should find a suitable one.

Answer (score 7):

Select all the file and reformat the code.. it´s simple tip! ;-)

On windows  ctrl + l and mac cmd+alt+l or whatever your configuration

Comment: I don't understand how it helps. I have the clean + minified file but I need to edit the minified one. I cannot refactor it because the point of the minified file is to remove every syntactly useless space charactets.

Comment: Sorry, I edited my comment (it was my mistake) instead of "refactor" --> "reformat"

Comment: @inane It doesn't work. JetBrains should solve this. They are losing innovation. VS Code has this plugin.

Comment: @ErdinçÇorbacı I edited the answer for Windows. It's ctrl+alt+l